# AS3 XML Inner Text with child nodes

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, google-translate, xliff

I'm working with the strings.xml file that is prepared according to google's translate services, which specifies that portions of your string that you don't want translated should be wrapped in a xliff:g tag like this: `<xliff:g>some text</xliff:g>`

for example, my strings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="rn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="game_starts_now">Game Starts Now</string>
    <string name="game_starts_in">Game Starts In <xliff:g id="seconds" example="20">{0}</xliff:g> seconds</string>
</resources>
```

if I trace out the first value by searching for the name "game_starts_now", it traces out as expected, but if i trace out "game_starts_in" it gives the full xml node that it exists in.

example:

```
trace((xml.string.(@name == "game_starts_now"))); // Game Starts Now
trace((xml.string.(@name == "game_starts_in"))); // [output is next 4 lines]
// <string name="game_starts_in" xmlns:xliff="rn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
//  Game Starts In
//  <xliff:g id="seconds" example="20">{0}</xliff:g>
// </string>
```

Is there a way to get the full inner text of the `<string>` without child nodes? I'd like to have the 2nd trace output the following text:

`Game Starts In {0} seconds`

Comment: Try `trace((xml.string.(@name == "game_starts_in")).text())` but you will get : `Game Starts Inseconds`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to access child nodes of XML is by using dot notation like you would with any normal object.  I would try using trace((xml.string.(@ == "game_starts_in").(@id =="seconds")));

Let me know if this works for you.